# asterisk agi (php) file debugging

Tags: php, command-line-interface, asterisk, agi

does anyone know the steps required to debug the agi secript (a2billing.php) of asterisk . I am able to remote debug php cli if i call it form the linux console. but if it runs from within asterisk , it does not work.

any idea how to debug it ?

Answer (score 6):

To turn debug mode of a2billing you have to go config, and in agi-confX put verbose ->DEBUG(see comments)

After that you can check a2billign debug file(specified in /etc/a2billng.conf) or do from console

```
asterisk -r
agi set debug on
core set verbose 4
```

that will typicaly give you enought info to debug script. it show lines and files where message invoked, so you can check thoose files and compare with log.

p.s. in general it is nice idea hire someone with a2billign experience. in most cases that will cost you MUCH less then understand logic of a2billing, it is not always clear.

Answer (score 0):

A2Billing can write debugging information to log files, see in the AGI code, any command starting with $A2B->debug(...)

In the AGI-Conf on the Admin UI, you will find settings to either verbose the log on CLI or to  select the verbosity level.