# displaying cookie value inside textbox

Tags: php, html

i have to display a cookie value in textbox
but the value is surrounded with a lot of space on both sides
i am appying trim() but still not fixing

```
 < ? php
 uName="";
 if(isset($_COOKIE["uName"]))
 { $uName=trim($_COOKIE["uName"]);}
 ?>
 <input type="text" name="uName" value="<?php echo $uName; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.
Error was here

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE["uName"]; ?>">
```

Now i have replaced this with

```
<input type="text" <?php echo "value='".$_COOKIE["uName"]."'"; ?> >
```

It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Please fix error in 1st line of your code:

```
$uName = "";
```

For debug purposes I use functions, described in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990414/asterisk-agi-php-file-debugging/)